# Multiple intents sharing the same slot value

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm writing an Alexa skill that captures a ticket number from one intent and captures age from different intent. and Basically, these two are of type number.

When I'm trying to enter a number, it is being captured in the first Intent's slot. Here is my intent schema.

```
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "TicketNumber",
          "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
        }
      ],
      "intent": "CheckStatusIntent"
    },
    {
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "ageAndCurrency",
          "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
        }
      ],
      "intent": "ClientSuggestIntent"
    }
  ]
}
```

and my sample utterances are

```
CheckStatusIntent I want to check on the status of a ticket
CheckStatusIntent {TicketNumber}


ClientSuggestIntent I have a client meeting tomorrow.
ClientSuggestIntent {ageAndCurrency}
ClientSuggestIntent {personName}
```

In my `ClientSuggestIntent`, the flow should be as below.

User:   I have a client meeting tomorrow.
Alexa:  What is the Client's name.
User:   Sara John
Alexa:  What is Sara John's age
User:   65

Here when I give `65`, instead of matching with in the `ClientSuggestIntent`, it is matching with the `TicketNumber` of `CheckStatusIntent`.

This is very confusing, please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use "state handlers" do do this. Here is a video I did that explains how to do it. https://youtu.be/ukR0Aw5P3W8.

If you're using the ask-sdk for node you'd use `Alexa.CreateStateHandler(...)` to create one state handler with your CheckStatusIntent function in it and another state handler with your ClientSuggestIntent function.

Also read https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs#making-skill-state-management-simpler

Comment: Thanks for the video, it really helped see how the the plumbing works.

Comment: @NealWalters glad it was helpful and thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate a bit on Steve's answer above, the problem is that Alexa cannot tell the difference between "CheckStatusIntent {TicketNumber}" and "ClientSuggestIntent {ageAndCurrency}" since both are just a number.

You need to either give Alexa a way to differentiate between each of your intents. For example, "ticket {TicketNumber}" and "my age is {age}".

Or alternatively, you can setup a context as described by Steve, and use a single intent to handle either/any number-only input.

I hope this helps clarify things. I know its complicated when your just getting started. I found it easiest to keep things very simple using multiple, unique intents.