# Alexa skills - fulfilling another slot in slot filling process

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I'm working in a skill that search for doctors by name or by specialty.

I have the intent: `FindDoctor`

It have 3 slots: `Type`, `Name` and `Specialty`.

### This is what I have right now:

When the user say:

> "I want to find a doctor"

Then my code will delegate the control to Alexa and ask for the `Type`:

> "Ok, do you oyu want to find it by name or by specialty?"

If the user ask for the `Name` or for the `Specialty`:

> "By specialty"

My code will delegate in the slot necesary to fulfill the intent for the user:

> "Perfect, which is the name of the specialty?"

And the user will fulfill it:

> "Traumatology"

The my code will call an API and find the results:

> "Here is the closest traumatologist....etc"

---

### This is what I'm trying to get:

What happend if the bot ask about the `Type`:

> "Ok, do you oyu want to find it by name or by specialty?"

And the user say:

> "A Traumatologist."

Then I want to fulfill the slot `Specialty` and don't need `Type`.

But when in the slot filling, I put as a possible answer of the user "a {Specialty}", I don't fulfill the slot `Specialty`, instead I always fulfill the slot `Type`.

---

So supposing I always ask the user about what he wants to find. Is there any way to fulfill another slot when I'm on `Type` slot filling in Alexa?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to fill multiple slots from a single intent. Here is an example of what this could possibly look like:

```
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "name": "FindDoctorIntent",
      "samples": [
        "Find a doctor",
        "Find doctor {DoctorName}",
        "{Specialty}",
        "Find a {Specialty}"
      ],
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "Specialty",
          "type": "LIST_OF_SPECIALTIES"
        },
        {
          "name": "DoctorName",
          "type": "AMAZON.US_FIRST_NAME" // or whatever type is best suited for your usecase
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "types": [
    {
      "name": "LIST_OF_SPECIALTIES",
      "values": [
        {
          "id": "traumatologist",
          "name": {
            "value": "traumatologist",
            "synonyms": [
              "traumatologist",
              "Traumatology",
                ...
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "other docter type",
          "name": {
            "value": "other type..",
            "synonyms": [
                 ...
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here are some additional resources that might be useful:
[Using Dialog Management to Capture A and B or C Slots](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/44dd83f4-4842-40c5-91f8-3868b9f4608c/using-dialog-management-to-capture-a-and-b-or-c-slots)

Another good question.. incase your two types are similar: [Multiple intents sharing the same slot value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46878839/5787099)